# update date in DatePicker cannot be applied in android error shown

Tags: android, datepicker

**I tried set date to datepicker it will showing an error...**

i send date using intent and it will set on next page...
that is my problem...

my code is

declare datepicker object,

```
DatePicker datePicker;
String mydate="2016-12-07";
```

and on create fn,

```
datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.schedule_datePicker);
String[] dateParts = mydate.split("-");
```

and i tried to set date using updateDate fn like,

```
datePicker.updateDate(dateParts[0], dateParts[1], dateParts[2]);
```

Please help me how can i solve this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, i hope helped you..

```
     final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel();
                //pick_date.setText(year+"-"+monthOfYear+1+"-"+dayOfMonth);
               // pick_date1 = year+"-"+monthOfYear+1+"-"+dayOfMonth;
            }
        };

 Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(BookNow.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                        String pick_times=selectedHour+":"+selectedMinute;
                        String converted_time=LibraryHelper.ChangeDateFormat(pick_times,"HH:mm","hh:mm a");
                        pick_time.setText( converted_time);
                    }
                }, hour, minute, false);//Yes 24 hour time
                mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                mTimePicker.show();

private void updateLabel() {

    String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the points below.

1. updateDate requires integer parameters.
2. Since you are using a pre filled string as date , why don't you consider adding the method as `datePicker.updateDate(2016, 12, 7);` ?

Answer (score -1):

yes i tried this way to got ans,

```
datePicker.updateDate(Integer.parseInt(dateParts[0]), Integer.parseInt(dateParts[1]), Integer.parseInt(dateParts[2]));
```